# PHP: Learning IF-ELSE-statement

Tags: php

What am I missing? Sorry for this very basic beginner's question.

Instructions:

On line 8, write an if / else statement, just like we did in the last exercise. Here's what the outline of the code looked like:

```
<?php
  if (this condition is true) {
    // do this code
  }
  else {
    // do this code instead
  }
?>
```

If your condition is true, your code should echo "The condition is true"

Otherwise (else) when it is false, your code should echo "The condition is false".

Make sure your condition evaluates to false, so that your program prints out "The condition is false".

**This is what I wrote:**

```
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <?php
      $myName = "Suzie";
      $myAge = 35;
        // Write your if/elseif/else statement here!
        if($myName = "Rachelle")
        {
            echo "Hello Rachelle";
        }
        else {
            echo "what is your name";
        }

      ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `=` is assign. `==` is assert if something is the same as another thing, and `===` is assert if they are the same type and value.

Comment: you're assigning in the if clause (using single equal sign) where you should be comparing for equality (double equal sign)

Comment: In your if statement, to check if a given variable is equal to another value/variable use `==`, `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison

Comment: it should be like this if($myName == "Rachelle")

Answer (score 4):

So lets see why your condition `if($myName = "Rachelle")` returns `true`,
the `=` operator is used to assign values to variables, now, PHP can cast an assignment operation to boolean, so it can "return" you a `true` value if the assignment has succeeded or `false` if it failed.

when you want to compare 2 values you should use the `==` operator:

`(2 == "2") // returns true, compares the value`

when you want to compare 2 values and thier types you should use the `===` operator:

`(2 === "2") // returns false, compares values and type`

Comment: For a beginnger it might be nice to clarify that you almost always want to use the `===` operator. You avoid so much confusion, such as `"php" == 0` returning true.

Comment: agree, it's a good practice to use the `===` operator most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigining the value but not comparing (`==`).

Correct is:

```
 if($myName == "Rachelle") {
    echo "Hello Rachelle";
 } else {
    echo "what is your name";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one!

```
 <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <?php
      $myName = "Suzie";
      $myAge = 35;
        // Write your if/elseif/else statement here!
        if($myName == "Rachelle")
        {
            echo "Hello Rachelle";
        }
        else {
            echo "what is your name";
        }

      ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of "try this one" an explanation for what was wrong would be very apropos.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double equal to parameter inside `if` condition to check the condition.
Otherwise its considered as the `assignment operation`.
Check the code below

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <?php
        $myName = "Suzie";
        $myAge = 35;
        // Write your if/elseif/else statement here!
        if($myName == "Rachelle") {
          echo "Hello Rachelle";
        }
        else {
          echo "what is your name";
        }
      ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```